# Logistic VS Linear

Tags: logistic

What other techniques can be used in place of a Logistic Regression model?

Also is there any other method besides MLE for estimating the Logistic Regression parameters?

Comment: What is the objective of your modeling?

Comment: What data have you got? In particular, what's the nature of your dependent variable (if you have one).

Comment: I have binary data i.e. 0,1 dependant variable and the explanatory variables are both categorical and continuous

Comment: I want to predict whether a customer will churn or not and what factors the churn might depend on

Comment: Any reason you feel logistic regression isn't sufficient for the job?

Comment: A common reason for not using logistic regression is over-dispersion (greater variance of the response than predicted by the best-fit binomial parameter), in which case a beta-binomial model can be used.  Is that what you have?

Comment: You can consider logistic regression to be a "supervised classifier". You can google that term to find other supervised classification methods. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning

Answer (score 1):

You could use Bayesian models, instead of pure MLE, the MCMCpack or the Zelig library in R will fit Bayesian logistic regression models

Answer (score 1):

This is a *classification problem*. Machine learning has a lot of tools to address problems such as these, e.g., Neural Networks, Support Vector Machines (SVM), Classification and Regression Trees (CART) etc.

Answer (score 1):

Consider survival analysis, such as cox regression, because time to churn is also important.
You can also consider exponential, gamma, weibull models along the lines of survival analysis.